# Novel about humans on a frozen planet

Tags: story-identification, novel, books

I'm trying to remember the title of a science fiction novel I read years ago about a frozen planet onto which some Earth explorers crash land. The natives don't smile except as an act of aggression(?) and the humans and aliens build a large ice ship with which to explore the planet. There was also a sequel to it, in which they explored even farther afield on the planet.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: @Alice: There is now an answer. If you think it is the correct one, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: Were the natives descended from a bird-like species?

Answer (score 12):

This sounds a lot like Alan Dean Foster's [*Icerigger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icerigger).

A ship is crashed on Tran-Ky-Ky and Ethan Fortune and Skua September lead the humans to a base using an iceraft.  The sequels are *Mission to Moulokin* and *The Deluge Drivers*.

The point is made explicitly that the native Tran do not show their teeth when smiling.

Comment: I concurr.  I re-read these books recently.  Everything matches the question here, apart from the "exporers crash landing" part, it was a couple of criminals, the people they kidnap, and acouple of  innocent parties who ejected from a larger ship and crash landed their escape pod.  But yes, this is the answer.

Comment: That's it!!!! Thank you so much for the answer! I didn't even know there were 2 sequels.